# C#, Cycle through TextBlock on button press, So close

Tags: c#

So I am working in C#, bit of a beginner, I have searched around but cannot find anything.

I have a TextBlock on my screen and a Button, each time the button is pressed I want the new text to be the content of the TextBlock, this is what I have so far however it only shows the last line, thanks.

```
 string[] arr = new string[4]; 
        arr[0] = "Hello and Welcome";               
        arr[1] = "To the new app";             
        arr[2] = "enjoy your stay";             
        arr[3] = "press next to continue";          

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            string s = arr[i];
            tbArray.Text = s;
        }
```

Comment: All of your code as written here will execute when you press the button once. So it will do the entire for loop all at once and obviously end on the last line. You need to make it **advance** one line, e.g., have a memory of what line it was on last, and add one. (You can use % 4 , aka remainder of dividing by 4, to go to 0 instead of 4 and thus wrap around)

Comment: I think you want  `tbArray.Text += s;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to display the next element from your array every time your button is pressed? You should store the current index of your array in a variable in your class and each time your button is pressed increment its value. Obviously, make sure you check that your index is not out of bounds.

```
public class Foo
{
    private int index = 0;

    private string[] arr = new [] { "Hello and Welcome",
                                    "To the new app",
                                    "enjoy your stay",
                                    "press next to continue" };     

    private void ButtonCallback(...)
    { 
         tbArray.Text = arr[index++]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example of this, sorry like I say I am very new to programming, thank you very much

Comment: I can't imagine how this wouldn't work. Make sure `index` is a field on your class, as is the array.

Comment: Aha yes this works perfectly now thank you! How would I go about stopping to make sure its not out of bounds!

Comment: A simple `if` statement which checks to make sure `index < arr.Length` If it's not I suppose you would want to set `index` back to 0 to cycle through all your text once again.

Comment: no problem, also, since you're new to stack overflow, it's usually good practice to mark the correct answer as the "answer". The little "tick" symbol next to the answer :).

Answer (score 1):

You are not storing each string, but only the last one.

Add a little `+` before your equals like so:

```
string[] arr = new string[4]; 
arr[0] = "Hello and Welcome";               
arr[1] = "To the new app";             
arr[2] = "enjoy your stay";             
arr[3] = "press next to continue";          

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    string s = arr[i];
    tbArray.Text += s;
}
```

It would be also nice to add a space or a new line as they will be squashed together this way.

Comment: This shows all the text in one go, I want it so it first will show the text in the array at position 0, then when the button is pressed again it shows it at [1] etc :)

Answer (score 0):

I immgine you always see `"press next to continue"` string. as this is the *last* string assigned to a text box. You have to aggergate all strings into the single one and final string assign to a text box.

Simple example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
  sb.Append(arr[i]); 
}

tbArray.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display new Text from array each time you press a button

Global "i" variable and your array "arr"

```
/* global variable */
var i = 0;
/* your array - e.g. javascript array */
var arr = ['Hello and Welcome', 
            'To the new app', 
            'enjoy your stay', 
            'press next to continue'];
```

Call this function

```
 function displayText() {
        if(i >= arr.length) {
            i=0;
        }
        yourTextBlock.Text = arr[i];
        i++;
    }
```